# jqGrid - Load data after click on titlebar, initially collapsed

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid-php

I would like to show initially the grid collapsed (only title-bar showing), then after clicking on the titlebar get the grid expanded, and data loaded from the server. After that, if I collapse the grid, then re-expand it, as data is already there, it shouldn't be loaded again. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! - use hiddengrid = true See  [Basic grid - Properties](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm)